# DJI Battery Null

Tags: android, battery, dji-sdk

After a successful connection to the aircraft meaning this

```
BaseProduct baseProduct = DJISDKManager.getInstance().getProduct();
Aircraft aircraft;
if (baseProduct == null || !baseProduct.isConnected() ||
            !(baseProduct instanceof Aircraft)
           || baseProduct.getModel() == Model.UNKNOWN_AIRCRAFT) {
       aircraft =  null
}
else {
  aircraft = (Aircraft)baseProduct;
}
if(aircraft!=null){
   aircraft.getBattery(); // returns null
   aircraft.getBatteries(); // returns null
   aircraft.getBatteryBox(); // returns null
}
```

I always receive `aircraft.getBattery()` or `aircraft.getBatteries()` or `aircraft.getBatteryBox()` null.

P.S. Device model is Matrice 600 pro, and I can print the device model when the aircraft is connected (it is truly connected).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Android use：
Battery.setAggregationStateCallback.

and，IOS use：
DJIBattery.aggregationDelegate = self;

Answer (score 0):

I got the same matter, when use M300 RTK，（IOS），self.aircraft.batteries